# How to connect oracle database in visual studio 2017 using Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: visual-studio-2012, oracle11g

How to connect oracle database in visual studio 2017 using Scaffold-DbContext

PM> Scaffold-DbContext 
 "Server=MYLTOP;Database=DBFirst;User ID=sa;Password=XXX;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded ODT for VS 2017?
[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html) is a link to downloads and a bit of background that you may find helpful.

Comment: I have already installed oracle development tool.I can easily connect oracle database using server explorer

Comment: So are you getting an error or do you not know the steps that follow?

Comment: while running Scaffold-DbContext  command it shows error like "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)"

Comment: go to services on your computer and look for Oracle and make sure that the status is running. 

I'm not all that clued up with Oracle, but SQL Server gives that same error when the Service for sql is not running